# Cache problem on entity view mode teaser

Tags: 8, entities, caching

I'm using two slightly different versions of a teaser of a node on two different pages. It's the same fields used for both, but different HTML around each field.

In both cases, I get the renderable array of my node this way :

```
$view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node');
$vars['renderable_node'] = $view_builder->view($referenced_node, 'teaser');
```

What I would like to have :

- Page Node 1
- Node 3 teaser version 1
- Page Node 2
- Node 3 teaser version 2

The problem is when I flush caches, the cache is set for the first time rendering the teaser of my node, but on my other page it render the same version.

Here is what I have then :

- Page Node 1
- Node 3 teaser version 1
- Page Node 2
- Node 3 teaser **version 1**

I looked into `['#cache']['max-age']` but I don't really want to set it to 0 because it's not appropriate for obvious performance reasons.

I see that there is also `['#cache']['keys']`, `['#cache']['context']` and `['#cache']['tags']` but not sure what to do.

Comment: Why not use two different display modes and use `$view_builder->view($node, 'teaser');` and `$view_builder->view($node, 'other_teaser');`?

Comment: That's a good remark indeed, but in my case, I'm in a preprocess_node where I render a node teaser from an other type. Some info differ based on the current node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem recently.
Adding a key to the `['#cache']['keys']` array as unique id solved my cache problem.
For your case it should be like this :

```
$view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node');
$vars['renderable_node'] = $view_builder->view($referenced_node, 'teaser');
$vars['renderable_node']['#cache']['keys'][] = "page_1";
```

On your second call to the teaser node then it should be like this :

```
$view_builder = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node');
$vars['renderable_node'] = $view_builder->view($referenced_node, 'teaser');
$vars['renderable_node']['#cache']['keys'][] = "page_2";
```

Comment: That sounds good indeed ! In my case, I use the current nid of my preprocess node to make a difference `$vars['renderable_node']['#cache']['keys'][] = $current_node->id();`